# How would you write this in a loop in Robot Framework

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, robotframework, web-testing

So I'm currently learning Robot Framework and instead of using repeating code, I'm trying to utilize loops to make my code easier to maintain. Unfortunately, I do not know how to solve this one where I want to put this into a loop. This is a series of questions with drop-down answers, and I want to choose a different answer every time my test runs. I have tried a couple of foor loop options but none of them work. Essentially each loop should click on the drop-down and choose one random answer until all the questions are answered.

```
Check if User can change "Company" information
    Scroll Element Into View                ${USER_MENU_SCROLL_TO_COMPANY_MENU}
    sleep                                   1s
    click element                           ${USER_MENU_CLICK_COMPANY_EDIT_BUTTON}
    ${random_description1} =                 Evaluate  random.choice(@{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION1})
    click element                           ${random_description1}
    sleep                                   1s
    click element                           ${USER_MENU_CLICK_DROP_DOWN_2}
    ${random_description2} =                 Evaluate  random.choice(@{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION2})
    click element                           ${random_description2}
    sleep                                   1s
    click element                           ${USER_MENU_CLICK_DROP_DOWN_3}
    ${random_description3} =                 Evaluate  random.choice(@{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION3})
    click element                           ${random_description3}
    sleep                                   1s
    click element                           ${USER_MENU_CLICK_DROP_DOWN_4}
    ${random_description4} =                 Evaluate  random.choice(@{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION4})
    click element                           ${random_description4}
    sleep                                   1s
    click element                           ${USER_MENU_CLICK_DROP_DOWN_5}
    ${random_description5} =                 Evaluate  random.choice(@{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION5})
    click element                           ${random_description5}
```

I tried something like this but it wants to concatenate the values in my variables.

```
FOR ${i} IN RANGE 1 5
    ${random_description} = Evaluate random.choice(@{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION}+${i})
    click element ${USER_MENU_CLICK_DROP_DOWN_}+${i}
    click element ${random_description}
    sleep 1s
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is building the name of the variables.
You could have your variables as a list of lists.

Here is my view of the solution for your current code:

```
FOR ${i} IN RANGE 1 5
    ${random_description} = Evaluate random.choice(@{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION${i}})
    click element ${USER_MENU_CLICK_DROP_DOWN_${i}}
    click element ${random_description}
    sleep 1s
END
```

EDIT -- That was the initial answer. Below is a proven solution.

```
*** Test Cases ***
Loop in menus
    @{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION1}=    Create List    question11    question12    question13    question14    question15
    @{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION2}=    Create List    question21    question22    question23    question24    question25
    @{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION3}=    Create List    question31    question32    question33    question34    question35
    @{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION4}=    Create List    question41    question42    question43    question44    question45
    @{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION5}=    Create List    question51    question52    question53    question54    question55
    @{USER_MENU_CLICK_DROP_DOWN_1}=    Create List    item11    item12    item13    item14    item15
    @{USER_MENU_CLICK_DROP_DOWN_2}=    Create List    item21    item22    item23    item24    item25
    @{USER_MENU_CLICK_DROP_DOWN_3}=    Create List    item31    item32    item33    item34    item35
    @{USER_MENU_CLICK_DROP_DOWN_4}=    Create List    item41    item42    item43    item44    item45
    @{USER_MENU_CLICK_DROP_DOWN_5}=    Create List    item51    item52    item53    item54    item55
    FOR    ${i}    IN RANGE    0    5
        ${random_description}=    Evaluate    random.choice(${USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION${i+1}})
        Log To Console    \nclick element ${USER_MENU_CLICK_DROP_DOWN_${i+1}}[${i}]
        Log To Console    click element ${random_description}\n
        sleep    1s
    END
```

Output:
[image: Console output]

Comment: The solution that you have written is something I tried but Robot Framework does not support nested Variables.

Comment: @AM0801 I had to do some changes, but found a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

After some tinking, I have found a solution. Maybe there is a more efficient way of writing this and I would like to know what that is if anyone has any suggestions.
My solution:

```
    Check if User can change "Company" information
    Scroll Element Into View                ${USER_MENU_SCROLL_TO_COMPANY_MENU}
    sleep                                   1s
    click element                           ${USER_MENU_CLICK_COMPANY_EDIT_BUTTON}
    ${random_answer1} =                      Evaluate  random.choice(@{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION_0})
    ${random_answer2} =                      Evaluate  random.choice(@{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION_1})
    ${random_answer3} =                      Evaluate  random.choice(@{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION_2})
    ${random_answer4} =                      Evaluate  random.choice(@{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION_3})
    ${random_answer5} =                      Evaluate  random.choice(@{USER_MENU_DROP_DOWN_QUESTION_4})
    @{random_answers} =     Create List     ${random_answer1}     ${random_answer2}      ${random_answer3}       ${random_answer3}       ${random_answer4}
    FOR    ${question}    IN    @{random_answers}
        click element    ${USER_MENU_CLICK_NEXT_DROP_DOWN}
        Click Element    ${question}
        Sleep    1s
    END
```